# Invoke Test Execution (Run Test) using Apex Code

Tags: apex, unit-test, test-setup

I don't want to run the apex code using the traditional approaches provided by the salesforce. I want to run the apex test execution using the Apex Code. Is there any way to do it?
And in which standard object the logs of the test that we have run is saved?

Answer (score 5):

Add on to the @Keith Answer. I assume that you have Test as keyword in your test classes, if yes you can use **[ApexTestQueueItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_apextestqueueitem.htm)** which will submit your test class for test execution asynchronously.

```
ApexClass[] testClasses = [SELECT Id FROM ApexClass WHERE Name LIKE '%Test%'];
if(testClasses.size() > 0) {
   ApexTestQueueItem[] queueItems = new List<ApexTestQueueItem>();

  for (ApexClass cls : testClasses) {
   queueItems.add(new ApexTestQueueItem(ApexClassId=cls.Id));
  }

  //it will submit them for execution
  insert queueItems;
```

Comment: Some important considerations to this method: 

1: This runs tests asynchronously, which seems to cause non-deterministic failures in many orgs.

2: The docs state: "If you insert multiple Apex test queue items in a single bulk operation, the queue items will share the same parent job".  

This does not seem to hold true over 200 records in our testing.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of suggestions - haven't tried either:

- The tooling API includes a `runTests` method and [Apex Tooling API - SOAP Edition](https://github.com/afawcett/apex-toolingapi) allows that API to be called from Apex.
- There is also a REST API - see e.g. [RunTest with Salesforce Tooling REST API (asynchronous and synchronous)](https://www.xgeek.net/en/salesforce/runtest-with-salesforce-rest-api/) - that you could call from Apex using the [Http Classes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http.htm).

**PS** Himanshu's approach looks a better way to go.